# Installing node.js via homebrew - Unlinked kegs

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I'me struggling to install node.js on my machine (macOS Catalina). When I brew doctor I got a warning saying that I have unlinked kegs. I tried to fix it but it wasn't possible.
Sould I ignore it or there's a way to fix it?

That's what I got on my prompt:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  node
Wicleices-iMac:usr wfabio$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.11.0... 

Error: Could not symlink lib/dtrace/node.d
Target /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node


To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
Wicleices-iMac:usr wfabio$ brew link --overwrite node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.11.0... 

Error: Could not symlink lib/dtrace/node.d
/usr/local/lib/dtrace is not writable.
```

[snapshot for the above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po7Fp.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to run:

```
sudo chmod +w /usr/local/
```

It would solve the directory issue.

It would be also nice to sort out the permissions for Homebrew in general as well:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /Users/$USER/Library
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
```

Let me know if that helps.